# Experiencing infinite loop in bits manipulation code in javascript

Tags: javascript

- I am trying to solve bit manipulation question using javascript
- In the question, given an input decimal number, converting to binary number and then manipulate bits based on two conditions to produce 0 bits at all positions
- first condition, on every i iteration LSB bit is flipped, and if bits from i+1 to end of the positions are zero, the value of bit at ith position is flipped
- On every bit manipulation operation, counter value is incremented and output returning the value of counter displaying bit manipulation operations occurred for the binary number
- In my code, I converted decimal to binary number and written conditions for bit manipulation operations, but the code experiences infinite loop and does not end
- can you guys let me know where I made mistake and help me to solve the issue with your suggestions
- providing the code below:

```js
var decimalNumber = 77;
var binaryBit = solution(decimalNumber);
console.log(binaryBit);
function solution (decimalNumber){
 var binary=[], i=0, j=0, binary_operations=0, binary_modified=[];
  while(decimalNumber > 0){
   binary[i] = (decimalNumber%2);
    decimalNumber = Math.floor(decimalNumber/2);
    i++;
  }
  console.log(binary);
  binary = binary.reverse();
  console.log(binary);
  while(!binary.every(zeroCheck)){
   //comBinaryOperation(binary);
  //}
  //function comBinaryOperation(binary){
  //for(var j=0; j<binary.length; j++){
   binary[binary.length-1] = (binary[binary.length-1] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    binary_modified = binary.slice(j+1, binary.length);
    console.log(binary_modified);
    if(binary_modified.every(zeroCheck)){
     binary[j] = (binary[j] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    binary_operations++;j++;
    if(j == binary.length-1){j=0;}
    /*while (binary.every(zeroCheck)){
     break;
    }*/
  }
  //}
  /*if(binary.includes(1,-4) ){
   binary_bit = 1;
  }*/
  console.log(binary);
  return binary_operations;
}
function zeroCheck(element){
 return element == 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `~` operator to flip?

Comment: @FedeSc...thanks for your reply...I can also ~ operator, but at that time, I thought of using conditional operator...now when I am executing program after the changes, inifinte loop taking place at creating binary_modified array... not moving forward to further statements in the code as I could able to see only modified array output in console...can you kindly look into it and provide your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going into infinite loop because this `while(!binary.every(zeroCheck))` is true. Infinite loops occur mostly in while loop `while(true)` will go to a infinite loop.

Try changing this line `!binary.every(zeroCheck)` to `binary.every(zeroCheck)` because `binary.every(zeroCheck)` returns a false.

Comment: @window.document....thanks for your reply...you have given a valid point...but for my case, I need to loop over and do bit manipulation operation until at the bit values at all the positions are zero and also changing condition to binary.every(zeroCheck), bit manipulation operation is not taking place...so can you kindly suggest how to place condition for getting finite loop